# How can I join a counter to the end of text and display the variable in a batch file

Tags: file, variables, batch-file, for-loop

I have a batch file that creates a variable for each line in a text file.
I am trying to echo only a certain number of variables based on user input.
My Code is

```
enter code here`set /p num=" What is the number of variables to display? "
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (data.txt) do (
SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
set var!vidx!=%%A
)
set var
pause
FOR /L %%H IN (1,1,%num%) DO ( echo varH%)
```

The first part of my batch works but it is the counter part I am stuck with.
I want the output to display the variable output for the number of lines set in %num%. I have tried lots of combinations of brackets and parenthesis etc.

TIA for any help.
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOR /L %%H IN (1,1,%num%) DO echo !var%%H!
```

Further details at [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)